# Avoid loading of invisible tiles when using multiple tile layers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) with two tile layers. The first one, I will call it *basement tile layer*, provides tiles for whole world. The second one overlays the basement tile layer in a specific region defined by bounce option. I will call this one *overlaying tile layer*. In code this looks like the following:

```
var map = L.map('map');

// OpenstreetMap tile layer as basement
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// overlaying tile layer for specific region defined by bounds
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.examples.com/overlay/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  bounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(59.321966, 18.05943), L.latLng(59.328469, 18.076167));
}).addTo(map);
```

The overlaying tile layer are not transparent. So for the bounds region only the tiles of overlaying tile layer are visible. Tiles provided by basement tile layer are not needed. But I didn't find a way to prevent Leaflet from loading these unnecessary tiles yet. I would be glad for any hint.

I thought about using tile events to interrupt loading of tiles which aren't needed. But as far as documented tile events can not manipulate tile loading.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bewh79ph/) demonstrating the behavior. As you see e.g. tile 14/4825/6155.png is loaded from openstreetmap.org even so it's invisible.

In my use case another think makes it more complicated: Overlaying map has strict borders cause it's generated by historic map sheet. So tiles are transparent at the borders of overlaying map. In these regions tiles of basement map has to be loaded.

Comment: I think you are asking how to get the overlay to display only inside the bounding box?   If that is your question it would be difficult to do with a tile layer.  You would be better served using a single tile request.  If you are in control of the overlay service, I would recommend using a single tile WMS setting on that server.  Otherwise, if you are required to use tiles you will need to do lots of magic to cut the tiles on the client side.  I am really not sure what you are asking though.  If you are simply asking the last paragraph just set the openstreetmaps layer to basemap true.

Comment: @FrankPhillips Restricting a tile layer to a specific area is supported by Leaflet out of the box by bounds option. As you can see in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bewh79ph/) this is working fine. My question is only about avoiding load of not needed tiles.

Comment: I was unclear if you were concerned about precision of your BBOX or the bandwidth usage.  You can prevent the loading but only grossly(remove the layer) easily.  That solution would be to attach to the _tileOnError event of your historical layer and if that happens add the basemap to fill in the gaps if there are any.  Other than that you would need to extend the tilemanger in leaflet so that both of the layer objects are aware of each other.  This would be a lot of work to save a seemingly very small amount of usage unless you have a very small set of hist maps and and alot of site usage.

Comment: There is not a good answer for this really.  But, take a look at http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2013/elegant-overlapping-with-photographic-layers-in-leaflet

Comment: I have created a PR to support this: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/7859.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @FrankPhillips hints in comment I figured out that I could overwrite `_isValidTile` method from L.GridLayer to achieve the functionality. I could add a *hole* option as a opposite to *bounce* option.

```
L.ExtendedTileLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({    
    _isValidTile: function (coords) {
        var crs = this._map.options.crs;

        if (!crs.infinite) {
            // don't load tile if it's out of bounds and not wrapped

            /*
             * this._globalTileRange is not defined
             * not quite sure why
             */
            var globalTileRange = this._map.getPixelWorldBounds( coords.z );

            var bounds = globalTileRange;
            if ((!crs.wrapLng && (coords.x < bounds.min.x || coords.x > bounds.max.x)) ||
                (!crs.wrapLat && (coords.y < bounds.min.y || coords.y > bounds.max.y))) { return false; }
        }

        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);

        // don't load tile if it doesn't intersect the bounds in options
        if (this.options.bounds &&
            ! L.latLngBounds(this.options.bounds).intersects(tileBounds)) {
            return false;
        }

        // don't load tile if it does intersect the hole in options
        if (this.options.hole &&
            L.latLngBounds(this.options.hole).intersects(tileBounds)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    },
});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [40.777838, -73.968654], 
    zoom: 14
});

new L.ExtendedTileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
    attribution: '© <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    hole: L.latLngBounds(
        L.latLng(40.791853, -73.967128),
        L.latLng(40.781455, -73.955713)
    )
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.',
    bounds: L.latLngBounds(
        L.latLng(40.791853, -73.967128),
        L.latLng(40.781455, -73.955713)
    )
}).addTo(map);
```

I [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bewh79ph/3/) to show it working.

`_isValidTile` is mostly just copyed from Leaflet original. I had to reimplement `this._globalTileRange` since is was undefined. Code is only working for leaflet-src.js, since `_isValidTime` is uglifyed in production build.

Comment: This is a great idea.  Completely forgot about _isValidTile.

Comment: Any idea how/if it's possible to implement this using L.TileLayer.wms() instead of L.TileLayer? Also can you see why this isn't hiding the tile over Scotland? http://jsfiddle.net/ravendarksky/hzkxdw3a/